# Strange text-box placeholders in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, browser, html, forms

I see following placeholders on every html form, in Google Chrome (my chrome version is 18 dev channel). What is that and how can I disable it?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like a problem with **Autofill**. Turn it off under **Settings** (`chrome://settings/personal`). If you use this feature, I suggest downgrading to a stable build of Google Chrome.